# How to change the database in a Rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

The database of my Rails application is SQLite3, but I want to change it to MySQL. What do I need to do to change it in my application?

This is database.yml from my application:

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the adapter to MySQL2 and add your credentials. For instance:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  database: development
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Look at the [offical documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-mysql-or-mariadb-database) for more information.

Here is it with defaults:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: development
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("username") %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("password") %>


test:
  <<: *default
  database: test
  username: username
  password: password

production:
  <<: *default
  database: production
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("username") %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("password") %>
```

You can also encode `username` and `password` in the database like this:

```
mysql://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>
```

and then set `host`. Don't put `username` and `password` in your database.yml file.

Comment: Thanks for answering me! How about default and test (you can check it how it is in myapplication right above). I need to change or it can stay of the same way ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change all your environments. The ``default`` section is shared settings, so would put the things like adapter, encoding, etc. from Christian's answer under default, and then set things like the database name and user/password separately for each environment.

Comment: I added an example with defaults. It also depends on your configuration to set a host and credentials etc. So without more details it's difficult to give an example.

Comment: Your test and dev **can** remain on sqlite when production is MySQL, If you want. It’s a little unclear if you are asking how to change them or if you need to change them when changing prod.

Comment: That is true @tom-harvey although I wouldn't recommend as it can lead to all sorts of surprises in production and nowadays with docker it's quite easy to run mqsql / postgres with the same versions as production.